# can we trigger some action if we `cd` into directory?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, alias

I have multiple projects over various languages like JavaScript, Python. I wonder if Linux provides some functionality to trigger some actions automatically if we `cd` into a particular directory?

For example, if I have a directory folder with node modules I want to activate the `grep` command as `alias grep='grep --exclude-dir=node_modules` or if I have a `.git` folder then I want to run certain commands as soon as I am `cd` into that directory. I am not asking for GUI mode it's fine if it only works for the terminal, or any particular shell-like `bash`, `zsh`.

Actually, I don't know what this feature is called and have never seen any kind of questions online, so I have asked. Maybe it's a shell feature but not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: The dup is for bash. In zsh, see the `chpwd()` hook function, and `chpwd_functions` array